# pulling and outputing php tags from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a dynamic FAQ page.  I have the following phtml sample :

```
<div id="faq">
    <!-- Start FAQ "Navigation" -->
    <div class="faqBox">
        <? foreach($this->aFAQ as $k => $val) : ?>  
            <?= ($val['mQuestion']); ?>
            <?= ($val['mAnswer']); ?>
        <? endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which outputs as follows:

For additional payment options - check or money order, please contact us at `iBrandingLevel == 2 ? $this->oStore->getSuppPhone()." Monday to Friday ".$this->oStore->getSuppHoursOpen()." - ".$this->oStore->getSuppHoursClose()." ".$this->oStore->getSuppTimeZone() : "(888) 455-3237 x2 from Monday to Friday 8:00am - 4:30pm MST/Arizona."; ?>`

The above text is just the first $val['mAnswer'] (I didnt include the question as that is working properly).

The html is being rendered however obvoiusly the php isn't. the `<?` and `?>` are being removed and just code is displaying. Is there a fix for this? or is my approach fundamentally wrong.

thanks

Comment: You're storing php code in the DB as a string that you want to run later?  Don't.

Comment: To expand upon Explosion Pills' comment, you should only ever have pure data in the DB, that's what it's for. Any code placed in there will be a real PITA to change or maintain. That's assuming that you have really really good security, and whatever is in your DB is always only going to be put in by you, as well.

Comment: I haven't downvoted anybody.  I didn't set up the db nor do I have the ability to alter the data.  Just looking for possible solutions.  Thank you for the input, I understand the basic issue is it shouldn't be done to begin with but like I said it was out of my hands

Answer (score 6):

Your approach is fundamentally wrong, you are outputting PHP code as if it was HTML text and try to execute it.

It is possible to execute code from a string, you can look at the Eval method (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.eval.php) in PHP, but it is not recommended to do this. There are better ways to resolve your specific issues than to output PHP code directly.

What you could do is send a few variables to the view, and use if conditions there.

You could also prepare the full string you need before the view and then all that would be needed is to display it.

To elaborate a little about Eval :

1- If the code you execute within the Eval comes from a user, it is extremely dangerous.

2- If not, there is very often a better solution to the problem, using Eval makes it harder to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm not sure I should answer this.

First, the answer to your request is the `mixed eval ( string $code )` [php function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

Second, FORGET IT. IMHO, this could be one of the most dangerous things you could think in.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for the input and resulting discourse. The php code that was being stored in the database was not being input by users, it was all completely internal, however it still shouldn't be there.

I ultimately went through the database and set a `%%variablename%%` in place of the php code and then upon retrieval I wrote a script that would:

`preg_replace("/\%\%variablename\%\%/", $desiredPhpcode,  dbRetrievedString)`.

all instances of `%%variablename%%`.

It seemed the safer and more sound approach.  I don't know if this is an IDEAL approach that anybody else could benefit from if caught in this circumstance or if it 'just works', but I thought I would share.

Thanks Again for the input it helped enormously

Answer (score -1):

PHP is server-side language. Outputting it to client does not make any sense, as there is no one to interpret it.

Comment: Someone thinks I'm wrong? Well, I"m here to listen to your arguments.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but you shouldn't take it as a personal attack. It's not that you are wrong, it's just that you've misunderstood the question. He is saying that his php code is being outputted to the user rather than being evaluated, which is what he is asking for.

Comment: @AlejandroColorado Yes, and I answer, that sending PHP to client is pointless, because there is no one to evaluate it.

Comment: As I say, it's not that you are wrong, cause you are not (although sending PHP to the client can be exactly what you are looking for: as a code snippet, a tutorial...) In this case, @user2101459 itself is saying this is not what he wants (he also considers it pointless).